# Entity Framework dynamic vs static include

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

Assume I have a simple class

```
public class foo
{
    public List<int> A {get;set;}
    public List<int> B {get; set;}
}
```

if I run

```
using(var ctx = new MyFooContext())
{
     var joins = ctx.foo.Include(x => x.A).Include(x => x.B).ToList();
     var includes = new List<Expression<Func<foo, object>>> {x => x.A, x => x.B);
     var noJoinQuey = ctx.foo.AsQueryable();
     includes.Each(i => noJoinrQuery.Include(i));
     var noJoins = noJoinQuery.ToList();
}
```

The first one, `joins`, will generat the query using join statements and run in one glorious statement. The second one, `noJoins`, executes a whole bunch of individual select statements. Why?!

Comment: Is that .Each supposed to be .ForEach?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. If I use Each, ForEach, or a proper foreach loop, it still doesn't not make the joins.

Comment: .Include() eagerly loads the associated entities, hence the joins.  I'm guessing that looping over the includes causes the expression to be evaluated and hence the several select queries.

Answer (score 0):

So, `.Include` is one of those functions that returns the object, so you can chain them like `query.Include().Include()`, but in a loop, it doesn't seem to do that. If I change it to

```
foreach(var p in includes)
{
    query = query.Include(p);
}
```

it works.